# Response.Redirect to another server in ASP.net 3.5

Tags: asp.net

In my application i want to link the user to yahoo.com.
I wrote the following code.

`Response.redirect("Yahoo.com")`

and it appends it with the application path!!!

Please send ur suggestions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
Response.Redirect("http://www.yahoo.com");
```

Answer (score 2):

That's a relative URL, relative to the requesting page.
You need to redirect to an absolute URL.

```
Response.Redirect("http://yahoo.com");
```

Comment: Good except for the fact that it should be `Response.Redirect` not `Response.redirect`

Comment: You both guys came at same time so give advantage due to "Redirect"